# Angular Material DialogModule

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-dialog

Some time ago I was directed to implement a Material Module to be shared in other modules

For brevity let's say it's this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

Then in another module, I import that module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MaterialModule
  ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

In a component in MyModule I want to reference a MatDialog but it seems I need to import again in the component

```
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

Is that the right way to do things?

It seems like a double import, once in the shared module, and then separately in the component which is part of a module which already imports the shared MaterialModule

Import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';

import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

I'm pretty sure I'm doubling up on imports, but the IDE (VS Code) is directing me to do this.

What's the minimum number of imports to reference MatDialog in my component? Specifically in the constructor

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}
```

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples is a simple example that doesn't have the shared MaterialModule.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need an import dialog module and dialog service. It is not a double import - it is different entities. Material example also has a shared module. Please see their [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xxpxavjvqxr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-content-example.ts).
[image]
Underlined - is the shared material module.

Comment: I'm still learning the best way to structure an Angular application and understood that defining a MaterialModule with only those features to be used in the app was one of the basic "building blocks". That block could be used or imported into other larger modules. But even after that import, it is still necessary to import individual items in components from the material library eg MatDialog from @angular/material/dialog. That feels like a double import. Thanks for Stackblitz reference - I guess best way forwards is to define any component using material within the Material Module.